# Is there an application that can unlock my computer via Bluetooth?

Tags: software-recommendation, bluetooth, lock-screen

I have a Mac and I use an application called [TokenLock](http://www.map-pin.com/tokenlock-home) that uses my iPod's Bluetooth signal to lock/unlock my computer when I get near/too far from it. Is there something like that for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

BlueProximity is an application that lets you automatically lock / unlock your (Linux) computer using a bluetooth device such as a mobile phone.<sup>[BlueProximity](http://blueproximity.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install blueproximity
```

Or you can download it from [here](http://blueproximity.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

You can also try [Proximity](https://github.com/revned/proximity).

Proximity monitors the proximity of your mobile phone or other bluetooth device and executes custom AppleScripts when the device goes out of range or comes into range of your computer. Purpose The intent of this project is for the source code to be critiqued by other developers in hopes of improving my Cocoa programming abilities, as well as my programming skills in general.<sup>[Proximity](https://github.com/revned/proximity)</sup>

Comment: Did you manage to get the blueproximity applet displayed? Proximity seems to be an OS X app?

Comment: If memory serves me right, I did, but was under 12.04.  Haven`t tried it under 14.04.